# Android: creating an animation on touch

Tags: android, animation

I wanted to create a frame by frame animation when the user touches the screen. The images I've decided to use should appear, animate and disappear at the touched coordinates.

```
<animation-list xmlns:android=
 "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation1" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation2" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation3" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation4" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

I attempted to do this via `drawable.animationdrawable` but it seems like I needed to have the image on screen in the `main.xml` before I can do this. Is there a way I can do it without having this code in the main.xml?

```
 <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/animation1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily set  source for your ImageView using java code. Get reference to imageview in xmllayout. for eg. imageview is image

then do image.setResource(a drawable to be passed here).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view  + add `visibilty_GONE` + add `set_anim` property, as you have defined your animation file.
2. Use some `onDown(MotionEvent e)`.
3. Inside this `onDown`, set your `view_visibilty_VISIBLE`.